# Django queryset length is 1 but doing .first() and .last() return two different objects

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django-queryset, django-orm

Encountered unusual behaviour django ORM query. Filtered queryset when printed displays only one value but when i tried doing .first() and .last() on that queryset it displayed two different values

In below query I have a document table in which there is foreign key --> user_id
One user can have multiple entries in document table. I want to find the latest entry id in document table for given user_id.
The queryset shows only one item but doing .first() is showing an item that is not even a part of the queryset. Why is this behaviour ?

qs = Document.objects.filter(user_id=1537).values('user_id').annotate(max_id=Max('id'))

Output: <QuerySet [{'user_id': 1537, 'max_id': 37}]>

qs.first()

Output: {'user_id': 1537, 'max_id': 33}

qs.last()

Output: {'user_id': 1537, 'max_id': 37}

Comment: The [first()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#first) documentation alludes to this, and they include a note about it. Likewise, the [order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-order-by) documentation explains it in more depth.

Answer (score 0):

Using values**('user_id')**, which results in an unordered queryset, is the cause of the unexpected behavior. There is no guarantee that the result of executing first() or last() will be the maximum value. So order by **'-max id'** to guarantee correct ordering.
Try this;

```
qs = Document.objects.filter(user_id=1537).values('user_id').annotate(max_id=Max('id')).order_by('-max_id')
```

Hope it's helpful :)